# My app registerForRemoteNotifications on OS after iOS 9 is ok, but before iOS 9 and use the iphone 4s or iPhone 4 it has trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, apple-push-notifications, iphone-4

I have used remote Notifications in my app but register failed when using iPhone 4 or iPhone 4s. For iPhone 6 and the others, there is no issue in registering. I search the problem on net. It is because of wrong Certificates. So I do not understand it. How can iPhone 6 or iPhone 5 successfully register while iPhone 4 or 4s does not. Maybe it is system version's issue. How can I solve this problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

Comment: yes,I have add this before I ask in stackoverflow ,I think it is the issue before iOS 9.0 or After iOS 9.0,or only in some device?Just iPhone4 or iPhone4s have this problem.